# Node.js install canvas failed on mac osx 10.8.4 : src/Canvas.h.....fatal error: v8.h file not found

Tags: macos, node.js

I install nodejs following nodejs wiki, it's going well, and then install node canvas following this way https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---OSX, the steps before "$ npm install canvas" were going well, but the final step "$ npm install canvas" was failed again and again, I have tried install the Nodejs both building and installing, and i also try "sudo", and I have try "$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=.....", but still can't install canvas, I'm sure I have followed all the guide clarely.
Below is the log:

```
SLMacs-MacBook-Pro-2:~ percy$ npm install canvas
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/canvas
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/canvas

> canvas@1.0.3 install /Users/macbookpro/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o
In file included from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
../src/Canvas.h:11:10: fatal error: 'v8.h' file not found
#include <v8.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:678:10)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.4.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/macbookpro/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.12
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.6
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! canvas@1.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.4.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "canvas"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/macbookpro
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.63
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: 'npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.4.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "canvas"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/macbookpro
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.63
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macbookpro/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem myself. You may need to install some dependencies. Try running the following command in terminal.

```
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg
```

Afterwards, rerun npm install. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it:

1. Download the source code of node 0.10.13 from http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.13/node-v0.10.13.tar.gz
2. Extract this file via tar -xvz node-v0.10.13.tar.gz
3. Copy the 'deps', 'src' and 'tools' folders into '~/.node-gyp/0.10.13'

Then run 'npm install canvas' again.

I have no idea why the MacOS node package(just for v0.10.13) is missing these things.